# How to run selected tests separately in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: automated-tests, nunit, visual-studio-2019, specflow

I have specflow in my Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, and I can run tests generated from my feature files without problem.

I have only one strange thing, that I cannot run selected tests under a feature, even if I select only one from it.

This is how it should look like:
[image: normal]

But this is how it looks like on my computer:

[image: strange]

These are my extensions:

[image: extensions]

And the nunit pacakges are:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run your tests through Test Explorer, or through a Test Results panel?

Comment: Through Test Explorer

Comment: When you click "Run" does it actually not run the test? Just trying to make sure this isn't a terminology change with a Visual Studio update, or a difference introduced by different flavors of Visual Studio (Professional vs Community, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup and I can run/debug individual tests from Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer.

Note that you can run an individual test if it is a "**Scenario:**" in the feature file but if it's a "**Scenario Outline:**", then all rows/tests in the "**Scenarios:**" for the Scenario Outline are ran.
This is different to Visual Studio 2017, where you can run an individual test/row from a Scenario Outline feature test.

Also, note you need the following 3 NuGet references for SpecFlow to work properly:
You might have different references dependent on you test runner (https://specflow.org/2019/updating-to-specflow-3/)

[image]

**UPDATE:** I was surprised by this behaviour and did some further testing. I got a colleague to try running the same individual "**Scenario Outline:**" test on his machine and it worked as expected for him, only running the selected test, which is what Visual Studio 2017 used to do.

At this stage I went for the nuclear option of **deleting the git repository and cloning it again**. This resolved the problem on my machine and I can now also run individual SpecFlow tests on any type as expected in Visual Studio 2019. This is all very strange but at least people can try this if they find themselves with the same problem.

**UPDATE 2:** Another solution may be to **delete the ".vs" folder**. You will find this folder where your solution (.sln) file exists. I haven't tested this as the problem has gone away for me but it's a less drastic measure that a delete and clone. Please let me know if anyone has this problem and this approach fixes it for you.